# How to remove tile with mesh embedded in cement bed?

Tags: bathroom, tile, subfloor, cement, demolition

I am doing a bathroom remodel on a late '60s house. The bathroom tile is set on a roughly 1.5" cement bed with embedded wire mesh. I have removed a small portion with a rotary hammer with a pointed bit and a 2lb sledge.

Is this the best / safest method. I am of course wearing proper saftey gear. I am more concerned about damaging the subfloor or framing. The tile is above an unfinished basement.

I've seen where people get under the metal mesh and try to pry the tile up. Is this a better method and how would I get started with it?

Comment: So you are taking up the mortar bed also? Be careful if screws were used to secure the wire in place you could really tear up the sub flooring.

Comment: Yes, mortar bed too. I would prefer to only remove the tile, but it is so well bonded to the mud bed that I don't think I would ever be able to to remove it and leave a usable bed. Planning to remove it down to the subfloor and replace with Durock or similar.